# Old Borland C programs

Tags: c++

I made many programs with Borlond C (Dos).
How can I compile\link these programs in modern computer with minimum effort?
Mainly, I mean to graphics programs.
Thanks in advance'
David.

Comment: you tagged this C++. Have you tried compiling them with a C++ compiler? which one? what happened? Is your issue actually compiling, or it is opening the project, or gaining access to the libraries your code was using that were supplied by Borland?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this port of the Borland Graphics Interface (BGI) to Windows: http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/cs1300/doc/bgi/

Comment: Another port of BGI is here: http://winbgim.codecutter.org/

Comment: You could also give this a shot: http://www.sandroid.org/TurboC/

Answer (score 1):

Just choose a new C/C++ compiler such as [MinGW/GCC](http://www.mingw.org/). And Recompile your source code. It may has many syntax issues but it's the only way.

Graphics - It's hard, you should forget old graphics methods and use new facilities such as Qt, GDI, wxWidgets. However you can use [Borland BGI Graphics emulation for the MingW (GCC port)](http://winbgim.codecutter.org/) to port your code as same as before.

Other alternatives are:

- [GRX graphics library](http://grx.gnu.de/)
- [Freeware BGI Drivers](http://www.von-bassewitz.de/uz/bgi.php)

Comment: @VladLazarenko: Yes, I missed that :-) However in DosBox you haven't modern C/C++ compilers.